# How do I apply a liip_imagine filter to every image in HTML code?

Tags: symfony, twig, liipimaginebundle

I know how to use liip_imagine on a single hardcoded image:

```
<img src="{{ '/relative/path/to/image.jpg' | imagine_filter('thumbnail') }}" />
```

No problem there.

Things get more complicated in a pretty common case though. I have some blog articles made with `IvoryCKEditorBundle`, with uploaded images in them.

I display the content of articles with `{{ article.content|raw }}` and my images in the content are obviously not resized, causing layout problems.

My question is pretty simple:

**How do I use liip_imagine when images are not hardcoded in Twig, but inside HTML code I don’t know in advance?** Should I build a Twig Extension to parse it?

Comment: This isn't a full-on answer, but I'd approach this problem by extending Twig with a new filter, like `myRaw` which does what `raw` does but also applies the thumbnail filter as well. Documentation on that can be found here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html

Comment: `merk` on Freenode just told me that the Twig extension solution would not work (the filter would be parsed away by Twig). The solution according to him/her would be to change the image size when uploading, with `ckeditor`.

Comment: I don't understand, I've done this before when I was implementing WordPress-like short codes. The phrase "parsed away by Twig" is what confuses me...

Comment: I guess he/she meant the tag would not be treated as a Twig filter. But If you say it can work, I guess I’ll try.

Comment: or you could make a listener and apply the filter when loading articles from db